# Is there a way to pass values between forms in vb.net? (Without using a public variable)

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that uses a second form with textBox and button, and i need to pass the text from textBox to the first form. I know how to do it with a public variable, but i would like to know if there is another way to do it without using a public variable.

Comment: What about the public variable option doesn't work well for you?  It would be helpful to know what it is you are trying to avoid.

Comment: This makes little sense, you certainly can't do it with a private variable.  I'll put a dollar on you actually talking about a *global* variable.  Yeah, don't do that.  How to use object references properly is well covered in any introductory book about Winforms, be sure to pick one up from your local bookstore or library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PUBLIC properties on the second form to read/write info to the other form.

You can overload the NEW method to pass variable during declaration.

You can create a public sub/function on the second form and pass variable byval or byref.

But, I would NEVER use a public variable.  That is bad programming.

Comment: Thank you i'm stupid not to think about public function, that works just fine:D

Answer (score 5):

Yes!

If the forms are part of the same solution, you simply write:

```
Dim MyVal1 As Integer = Form2.MyVal
```

MyVal1 exists in whatever form you write it in, and MyVal2 comes from Form2. These variables can only be shared if the forms have the right privacy settings.

If the two forms are part of separate applications, the only way i know of passing variables around is through constructors.

EDIT:

In your case with a textbox, you may be able to apply similar a solution:

```
Dim val As String = Form2.TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: That doesn't work if  use private variables. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Liewyec This is the definition of privacy, if the variables are private, they can only be accessed within their declared scope. By definition, what you are asking is impossible with private variables.

Comment: As Steve written below its posible if u use public function that sets the variable

Answer (score 0):

To pass a text variable use clipboard:

```
Clipboard.SetText(variable)
```

On other forms:

```
myvariable = Clipboard.GetText
```