# Update datagridview in different forms

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, owner

I can't insert a string before a datagridview
How can I pass Form1..Form2..Form3 variable to datagridview?

I have a datagridview with the same name in multiple forms I need to get the values ​​from them by changing the name **"FORMNAMEXXXX"**.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value

```
Dim ownerType = Owner.GetType()
Dim formowner = ownerType.Name.ToString
Dim id As Integer = formowner.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

but I have this error: 'DataGridView1' is not a member of 'String'

Comment: No, you definitely don't need to do that. What should be happening is that those other forms pass in the appropriate data when they create this form. Either declare a constructor with a parameter for this ID or else declare a property. Those other forms can all then pass an argument to the constructor or set the property. This form doesn't need to know anything about the form that created. All it needs is that ID value, not where it cam from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to pass values between forms in vb.net? (Without using a public variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966080/is-there-a-way-to-pass-values-between-forms-in-vb-net-without-using-a-public-v)

Comment: can you give me an example how to pass the value of a datagridview cell from one form to another via showdialog?

Comment: @GuidoM. Why would you need to go via a dialog? Does [Property Examples](https://www.dotnetperls.com/property-vbnet) help? (You'd want a `Public ReadOnly` property.)

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711574/send-data-within-child-forms/69743297#69743297

Comment: I have 3 forms, in form1 and form2 there is a datagridview. with the form3 I have to get the value of the cell of the form that called the form3. this is my requirement. I don't want to create one Public property.
I was able to get the name of the form which called form3 but if I use XXXXNAME.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString I have this errore 'DataGridView1' is not a member of 'String'

Comment: @GuidoM. Are you using the "default instance" of Form3 or do you make a new instance of it when you want to use Form3? And what do you mean by "called"?

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing or what the overall objective is. Your app may benefit from re-evaluating the design, but it's difficult to determine from the information provided. Please add images of your forms to your OP (original post). Also add details about what the overall objective of the project is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 3 forms, in form1 and form2 there is a datagridview. with the
> form3 I have to get the value of the cell of the form that called the
> form3. this is my requirement. I don't want to create one Public
> property. I was able to get the name of the form which called form3
> but if I use XXXXNAME.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
> I have this errore 'DataGridView1' is not a member of 'String'

So in Form1 and Form2, you need to pass in the "owner" when you display Form3:

```
' ... in Form1 / Form2 ...
Form3 f3 = new Form3()
f3.ShowDialog(Me) ' <-- pass in Form1/Form2 via "Me"
' ... or possibly ...
f3.Show(Me)
```

Now over in Form3, you can use the `.Owner` property to get a reference to either Form1 or Form2. Afterwards, you can SEARCH for that DataGridView "by name":

```
' ... in Form3 ...
Dim frm As Form = Me.Owner
Dim ctl As Control = frm.Controls.Find("DataGridView1", True).FirstOrDefault()
If Not IsNothing(ctl) AndAlso TypeOf ctl Is DataGridView Then
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = DirectCast(ctl, DataGridView)
    ' ... do something with "dgv" ...
    Debug.Print(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
End If
```